# jQuery Conflict with Collapsible List

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, conflict

I'm currently using a small jQuery script, included *infra*, to make lists with the class `collapsible-list` collapsible/expandable.  By default, the script collapses the list (and a bit of CSS, also included *infra*, makes this easily noticeable for visitors) and then expands it when a visitor clicks on expandable elements.

Here are the scripts:

**The jQuery**

```
jQuery(function($) {
function prepareList() {
    $('.collapsible-list').find('li:has(ul)')
        .click( function(event) {
            if (this == event.target) {
                $(this).toggleClass('collapsible-list-expanded');
                $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
            }
            return false;
        })
        .addClass('collapsible-list-collapsed')
        .children('ul').hide();
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    prepareList()
});
});
```

**The CSS**

```
/* Collapsible Lists */
.collapsible-list, .collapsible-list ul, .collapsible-list li {
    list-style: none;
}
.collapsible-list .collapsible-list-collapsed:before {
    content: "+ ";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00AA00;
}
.collapsible-list .collapsible-list-expanded:before {
    content: "- ";
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #AA0000;
}
```

The CSS is included for the sake of completeness, it functions exactly as expected.  The issue lies with the jQuery (and likely some other script on the page, which I cannot seem to isolate).

The script *does* collapse all but the top-level sections of any list given the `collapsible-list` class, but that's where the proper functionality ends.  Now, the script behaves as expected in my test environment (and also in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/9B2bP/1/)); however, once the script is implemented in my site, the lists collapse, expand one click, **but**, instead of staying expanded after being clicked (as they should), they immediately collapse again.  This, quite obviously, renders the script useless once implemented, as any list on which it is invoked by the `collapsible-list` class is made unusable for visitors.

Here is a link to a page where it is currently implemented: http://wpmudev.docs.omnifora.com/docs/plugins/wpmu-dev-dashboard/.  Now, I'm sure there is a script conflict somewhere, but I cannot seem to figure out what script is conflicting.

**Additional Information**

This site uses Bootstrap, which, I suspect, might be the source of the conflict.

**Updates**
I've narrowed down the potential conflicts, and it seems that Bootstrap may *not* be the culprit.  Here is a JSFiddle with the list behaving as expected within two different Bootstrap panel setups (nested within `panel-body` and nested within `panel`): [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/9B2bP/4/).

I've now managed to get the list working *except* as to formatting.  The jQuery conflict seems to have been caused by a slight error in the way one script was calling another, which leads to the `collapsible-list.js` file being loaded twice.  Here's a working JSFiddle: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/9B2bP/5/)

Answer (score 1):

It might work to add a `.toggleClass('collapsible-list-collapsed');` in your click function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after fiddling with this for a few hours, I was able to resolve all of the conflicts and get it down to a single remaining CSS issue, which was easily fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with things for a few hours, I was able to resolve the conflicts:

1. One of the script references was improperly formatted, and that was resulting in two calls to `collapsible-list.js`, which was causing the unexpected immediately-contract-upon-expansion behaviour.
2. The original script used just `expanded` and `collapsed` as classes, which was interacting with another set of rules and causing unexpected behaviour; the modified script uses more specific classes, which avoid such conflicts.

and then amend the CSS:

1. Someone had thought it wise to put `padding: 0;` onto `ul` and `li` elements in the theme's primary CSS file; this was, obviously, easily overridden with a more specific rule for `.collapsible-list`.

The result is that the page is now functioning as expected: http://wpmudev.docs.omnifora.com/docs/plugins/wpmu-dev-dashboard/.